# Hasmany relationship for fetching multiple table data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have three table to store category. One is Primary Category, another is Secondary Category and third is final category. Now I want to get final category with Primary category.

I can get Secondary categories with Primary through relationship by doing this is PrimaryCategory Model:

```
public function secondaryCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SecondaryCategory');
}
```

But Now while getting Secondary Category, I want to get final category in the relation object of Secondary category.

What I mean is Secondary categories should come in the relation object of Primary category and Final category should come in the relation of Secondary Category. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Category Model**

```
public function secondaryCategories(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SecondaryCategory');
}
```

**Secondary Category Model**

```
public function finalCategories(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\FinalCategory');
}
```

**Now while you are getting record from primary category it will become this way**

```
$categories = PrimaryCategory::with('secondaryCategories.finalCategories')->get();
```

*Note this `.` will create a nesting level like on 1st level you will have primary categories and on second level you will secondary and on 3rd you will have final categories.*

**You can also load only final categories via secondary categories with hasManyThrough relation**

**Inside Primary Category Model**

```
public function finalCategories()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\FinalCategory', 'App\Models\SecondaryCategory');
}
```

**Then do this**

```
$categories = PrimaryCategory::with('finalCategories')->get();
```

See docs for facing any issue while using different primary keys or foreign keys
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making a small change on your defined method.

**Replace this:**

```
public function secondaryCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SecondaryCategory');
}
```

**To:**

```
public function secondaryCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SecondaryCategory')->with('finalCategory');
}
```

And add the following method to your **Secondary Category model**.

```
public function finalCategory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\FinalCategory');
}
```

This will fetch final category inside the Secondary Category.

Comment: It isn't a best way, because it will always load the final category. In some cases he won't need to load the final categories but the approach you have provided will always load the final categories whether he wants or not.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I tried your method. It is returning same result as my method. I did not understand the place where he would not need to load the final categories. I would like to know because I think I can learn a new thing from you.

Comment: Yes of course it will return the same result. Suppose he wants to show primary and secondary and he doesn't need final categories and also in dropdowns, if he wants to show categories one by one procedure.